# Extract source code from .sppkg file

Tags: spfx

Is it possible to extract code from a SharePoint Package file? I have a package installed in App Catalog. Is it possible to get the SPFx code from the package file?

Answer (score 3):

Rename it to a .zip extension and extract it. But you won't get the typescript, you'll get the bundled JS.

Comment: ok from Bundled JS, is it possible to extract code?

Comment: no, it isn't...